# Remove action from url in asp.net mvc razor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a url like this: 
http://localhost:57482/ModuleName/Index/Value

I want to change it like this: http://localhost:57482/ModuleName/Value

**Code in RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{Category}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", Category = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You need to remove `{action}` from the `url` but keep it in the `defaults`.

Comment: You need to change in default route url. Just remove {action} part

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying your URL as being of the format `{controller}/{action}/{Category}`, and in the next line you say `action = "Index"`. So, instead of:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{Category}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", Category = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

try:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{Category}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "", Category = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Not sure if you need the `action = ""` part, so you might as well try omitting it